# Tridion Razor View nested foreach

Tags: dd4t, schema

I am creating a Page in SDL Tridion that allows producers to modify the `robots.txt` file for our site on the fly without requiring a code deployment.

I have the following Schemas:

- **Robots** that contains:

  - userAgentCollection (Embedded Schema)
  - sitemap (text)
  - modifiedDate (Date)
- **userAgentCollection** (embedded schema) that contains:

  - userAgent (text)
  - disallow (Embedded Schema)
  - crawlDelay (text)
- **disallow** (embedded schema) which contains:

  - Disallow (text)

I have a form that allows the user to add multiple user agents and each user agent can have multiple disallows.

My razor has the following code:

```cs
@model DD4T.ContentModel.IPage

# Modified @Model.MetadataFields["modifiedDate"].Value
@foreach(var userAgent in @Model.MetadataFields["userAgentCollection"].EmbeddedValues) 
{ 
    User-agent: @userAgent["userAgent"].Value
    foreach(var disallow in @userAgent["disallow"].EmbeddedValues) 
    {
        <span>Disallow:  </span>@disallow["Disallow"].Value<br />
    }
    <span>Crawl-delay:  </span>@userAgent["crawlDelay"].Value<br />
}
Sitemap: @Model.MetadataFields["sitemap"].Value
```

When it renders I get

```
# Modified 2013-11-20
User-agent: BingBot
Disallow: /c/noindex*
Crawl-delay: 1
User-agent: GoogleBot
Disallow: /foo/
Crawl-delay: 1
Sitemap: http://foo.com/sitemap.axd
```

But what I want is

```
# Modified 2013-11-20
User-agent: BingBot
Disallow: /c/noindex*
Disallow: /WCM/
Disallow: /FooToo/
Crawl-delay: 1
User-agent: GoogleBot
Disallow: /foo/
Crawl-delay: 1
Sitemap: http://foo.com/sitemap.axd
```

Only the first item in the `disallow` collection for each `useragent` is getting rendered.

Can anyone see what is wrong?

Comment: @Rhonda to properly format your code indent it with 4 spaces, see also http://tridion.stackexchange.com/help/formatting and http://tridion.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code, it is not just the code that is messy, your question seems to start with `0 down vote favorite`?

Comment: @Rhonda I see you copied your question from stackoverflow, please don't do that. You can flag it for moderator attention and ask it to be migrated in the future. Or just close it there when you want to post it elsewhere. I have indented your code and formatted the rest, please have a look to what I did and adjust where needed.

Comment: Not that this is related to your issue but is HTML allowed in a robots.txt file?

Answer (score 3):

Not a direct answer to your question, but as your **disallow** embedded Schema only seems to contain a single text field, I would recommend to remove the Embeddable Schema and change that in a Multiple Value Text Field.

Then you could also just loop over `Field.Values`, although I agree it is a bit strange that your code doesn't seem to work. At first look I would expect that to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

@Rhonda: Can you please check in your broker database, if you are able to find all the values for the "Disallow" attribute. If not the issue could be in your Component Template,the number of linked level might be less, try to increase the same.

Comment: I'm not sure the LinkLevel is to blame here, since it only impacts component links, not embedded fields.